# rails - Displaying image in view after uploading a file via Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I have a project that is on rails `5.1.2` and I am trying to implement Active Storage on it, following couple of tutorials online I am able to setup the Active Storage and I can see the data being saved inside the `active_storage_blobs` and `active_storage_attachments` table.

1. [Tutorial 1](https://rubyinrails.com/2017/07/21/rails-introduces-active-storage-for-file-uploads/)
2. [Tutorial 2](https://afreshcup.com/home/2017/07/23/activestorage-samples)

I also confirmed by running `user.avatar.attached?` and in response I got true so things are working.

What I am having problem with is displaying an image in view, I have tried

```
<%= image_tag(url_for(user.avatar)) %>
```

> NoMethodError: undefined method `active_storage_attachment_path'

**What I have done to setup Active Storage**

Ran the install command

```
rails active_storage:install
```

This gave error *Don't know how to build task 'active_storage:install'*

but the following command worked

```
rails activestorage:install
```

I have added `gem 'activestorage'` inside `gemfile`

This is what I have inside my `storage_services.yml`

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

Inside my `development.rb` I have added

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

Inside my `User` model I have added `has_one_attached :avatar`

Inside the controller on update I added the attachment code

```
user.avatar.attach(params[:user][:avatar])
```

1. I can see the image being added in database,
2. I can see the image being saved in the storage directory on root

Yet I am not able to display it,

What am I missing here? What do I need to do to get the image to display in the view? Why am i getting this error

> NoMethodError: undefined method `active_storage_attachment_path'

Answer (score 12):

You are doing wrong, you need to replace following code

```
<%= image_tag(url_for(user.avatar)) %>
```

with

```
<%= image_tag(user.avatar) %>
```

url_for is used to generate exact url not image tag.

Comment: It is also worth noting that it works the same with Rails instance variables, for instance: 

`<%= image_tag @user.avatar %>`

Answer (score 5):

Can you check your `config/appication.rb` file if you have added this line:

```
require "active_storage/engine"
```

I would recommend you to upgrade your rails version to `5.2 beta` as it has merged with Active Storage gem. If your application is covered with a good coverage of tests you can do it now. There are not so many changes from 5.1 to 5.2 see http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_2_release_notes.html .But it is not yet stable so you need to check if you can take that risk.