# Rails 5.2 (Upgrade) - Active Storage does not display image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

So I have upgraded from rails 5.1 to 5.2

```
rails app:update
```

It all works well, and I instantly set up the active storage configuration to be used with a new section in the web application.

I created the migrations:

```
rails active_storage:install
rake db:migrate
```

I configured conf/storage.yml - production using AWS S3:

test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id) %>
  secret_access_key: <%= Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key) %>
  region: eu-west-2
  bucket: whatever

Adding the required GEM to GEMFILE:

```
gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
```

Making sure that Dev environment uses the local setup:

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
```

Adding all the required lines to the model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :main_picture
  ... 
end
```

I did some fancy stuff, such as validation, custom variants, etc. - but for testing purposes and getting the basics working I commented out all that stuff.

Update Controller to use permitted attributes specified in Pundit:

Controller

```
@article.update(permitted_attributes(@article))
```

Pundit

```
class ArticlePolicy < ApplicationPolicy

  ...

  def permitted_attributes
    if !user.nil? && user.admin
      [:title, :content, :teaser, :slug, :published, :user_id, :main_picture]
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

Now the upload works like a breeze - to my local environment and I even tested uploading it to AWS, but let's stick to the local environment. I can find the latest upload on the local environment in:

```
/storage/N1/Ay/N1AyNaBeMNGhhmPSR69XwA9a
```

And that is the URL when I try to display the image in my view:

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBQQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--fd200a456532a80dfb122b2bdd9a53181b2a62aa/428KB.jpg
```

It appears like this in active_storage_blob table:

```
id,key,filename,content_type,metadata,byte_size,checksum,created_at
"55","N1AyNaBeMNGhhmPSR69XwA9a","428KB.jpg","image/jpeg","{""identified"":true,""width"":1920,""height"":1080,""analyzed"":true}","428299","48c8G3xQj5ENGgqqM08seQ==","2018-07-24 15:21:11"
```

Here is the various ways I tried to display the image:

```
= image_tag @article.main_picture
= image_tag url_for(@article.main_picture)
= image_tag @article.main_picture.variant(resize_to_fit: [100, 100]
```

None of these options displays the image that was successfully uploaded and stored in the DB. All I get is the image placeholder.

For the latest to work (but didn't) I added the following to the GEMFILE (as per [guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html)):

```
gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'
```

There is a [similar threat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971979/rails-displaying-image-in-view-after-uploading-a-file-via-active-storage?rq=1) complaining about this - using Rails 5.1 and adding active_storage in the Gemfile - but there is no real answer. As suggested I tried adding:

config/application.rb

```
require 'active_storage/engine'
```

Didn't help displaying the image :(

--- UPDATE: The logs as requested when accessing the URL ---

```
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBQQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--fd200a456532a80dfb122b2bdd9a53181b2a62aa/428KB.jpg" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-25 12:41:36 +0100
Processing by ActiveStorage::BlobsController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"signed_id"=>"eyjfcmfpbhmionsibwvzc2fnzsi6ikjbahbqqt09iiwizxhwijpudwxslcjwdxiioijibg9ix2lkin19--fd200a456532a80dfb122b2bdd9a53181b2a62aa", "filename"=>"428kb"}
** [Localeapp] 1532518896 - Handling translation updates
** [Localeapp] 1532518896 - polling
** [Localeapp] API CALL: get https://api.localeapp.com/v1/projects/qXa7rByH1jQ9cNrU8t46zQkk8rkq3fMka13EACmQkXZ5FFTuUn/translations.yml?updated_at=1532518849
** [Localeapp] ATTEMPT 1
** [Localeapp] RESPONSE: 200
** [Localeapp] CALLING SUCCESS HANDLER: handle_success
** [Localeapp] 1532518897 - poll success
** [Localeapp] 1532518897 - reloading I18n
Filter chain halted as :set_blob rendered or redirected
Completed 404 Not Found in 917ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/rails/active_storage/blobs/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBQQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--fd200a456532a80dfb122b2bdd9a53181b2a62aa/428KB.jpg?disposition=attachment" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-07-25 12:41:39 +0100
Processing by ActiveStorage::BlobsController#show as JPEG
  Parameters: {"disposition"=>"attachment", "signed_id"=>"eyjfcmfpbhmionsibwvzc2fnzsi6ikjbahbqqt09iiwizxhwijpudwxslcjwdxiioijibg9ix2lkin19--fd200a456532a80dfb122b2bdd9a53181b2a62aa", "filename"=>"428kb"}
** [Localeapp] 1532518899 - Handling translation updates
** [Localeapp] 1532518899 - polling
** [Localeapp] API CALL: get https://api.localeapp.com/v1/projects/qXa7rByH1jQ9cNrU8t46zQkk8rkq3fMka13EACmQkXZ5FFTuUn/translations.yml?updated_at=1532518897
** [Localeapp] ATTEMPT 1
** [Localeapp] RESPONSE: 200
** [Localeapp] CALLING SUCCESS HANDLER: handle_success
** [Localeapp] 1532518900 - poll success
** [Localeapp] 1532518900 - reloading I18n
Filter chain halted as :set_blob rendered or redirected
Completed 404 Not Found in 837ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

NOTE:

I added an image download button to generate the log:

```
= link_to "Download", rails_blob_path(@article.main_picture, disposition: "attachment")
```

Comment: You did not say if the URL works, do you see the image if you put the link directly in your browser ?

Comment: Hi, no the URL does not work. Also the console responds with a 404 that the image cannot be found.

Comment: Could you print the full logs when you try the URL

Comment: Sure thing - attached them to the original threat :)

Comment: Your signed_id seems invalid, it is why you got a 'Filter chain halted as :set_blob rendered or redirected'. Now, why, I can't tell, could you try this in a console with your signed_id (**--**), and check that the result, normally an integer

Comment: You notched me into the right direction: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32959 - Let me try this: It appears that the issue is related to the use of the route_downcaser gem in my application, which was forcing the signed_blob_id to lower case before it was fed into the controller. This can be seen if you look closely at the GET response snippet I posted from the server log.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176717/discussion-between-georg-keferbock-and-dinatih).

Comment: Missing part of my precedent comment : try this ActiveStorage.verifier.verify("eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBBc1FjIiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--2cc68988d071a4ea43f070954a1a68c56dcc7a68", purpose: :blob_id) with your on signed_id

Comment: Nope removing the route_downcaser solves it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your signed_id seems invalid, it is why you got a 'Filter chain halted as :set_blob rendered or redirected'.

Adding to the response:

The problem was caused by case-sensitive URLs. The GEM "route_downcaser" was installed. Upon removing this GEM everything worked as expected.

Also, "route_downcaser" offers the option of excluded_patterns. So you can use the GEM together with active_storage but make sure you add the following to the initializer:

```
# config/initializers/route_downcaser.rb

RouteDowncaser.configuration do |config|
  config.redirect = true

  config.exclude_patterns = [
    /assets\//i,
    /fonts\//i,
    /active_storage\//i
  ]
end
```

More configuration options can be found [here](https://github.com/substancelab/route_downcaser) :)